# Vaadin ListSelect - multiple styles in one list

Tags: css, vaadin

i would like to have one list select that will have more than one style, i put two kinds of object's one is a group of users (bold), rest are users (italic or regular) is it possible to add style that will be added to part of added obj?
My code looks like this:

```
    for(Usr usr: userSearchResult){
    listSelect.addItem(usr);
    }
    listSelect.addStyleName("bold");
        for (Gr gr : groupSearchResult) {
            searchList.addItem(gr);
    }
```

and also have style set in css correct similar to this

```
    .v-select-bold .v-select-select {
    font-weight:bold;}
```

i would be glad to solve this by myself but that was two days ago now i'm in a dot ;)
Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Check out [this vaadin.com thread on ListSelect items styling](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/1495117). It seems there's no standard way to style rows of listselect.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your row as a label with style. In the container there will be a label instance. There you can simply add the style.

```
    Container container = new IndexedContainer();
    container.addContainerProperty(NAME_PROPERTY, Label.class , "");

    for (int i = 0; i <= 50 ; i++) {
        Item item = container.addItem(i);
        Label label = new Label(HashUtils.getRandomSalt());
        label.addStyleName(style)
        item.getItemProperty(NAME_PROPERTY).setValue();
    }
    return container;
```

Comment: This is incomplete and doesn't even compile. What's NAME_PROPERTY?

Answer (score 0):

You can't style rows of a ListSelect. You can use a Table component with one column to achieve a similar result. `Table.setCellStyleGenerator` method is used for differentiating styles for each cell (each row in your case).

Comment: It's not possible you say, in java there is no such word, we just simply dont know how. If i would like to have table i would use table i even do and i manage to color it, but my problem is like follows and i need to find a way. 
Thanks anyway

Comment: Your question is about Vaadin ListSelect. I pointed out that it is not possible with standard Vaadin ListSelect. You can however extend the client-side widget of ListSelect.

Comment: I dig up a little more and to be honest, for Vaadin ListSelect there is no way of doing this... class select have options inside and setting style for option is not possible, its only possible for class -> all elements inside.
So thanks and im going to solve this other way.